# Efficiently extract duplicate/multiple paths with igraph

Tags: r, igraph

How can one extract duplicate paths from igraph and is there a more efficient way than the double loop in the example below?
By duplicate/multiple paths I mean that the result should contain both `B1 -> B2a -> B3` and `B1 -> B2b -> B3`. But my code does not yield that.
The data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

d <- tribble(~input, ~output,
             "A1", "A2",
             "A2", "A3a",
             "A2", "A3b",
             "B1", "B2a",
             "B1", "B2b",
             "B2a", "B3",
             "B2b", "B3")
```

My analysis:

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d, directed = TRUE)
(finals <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "out") == 0])
(starts <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0])
res_collect <- vector("list", length(starts) * length(finals))
tmp <- 1
for (i_s in seq_along(starts)) {
  for (i_f in seq_along(finals)) {
    res <- tryCatch(
      {
        all_simple_paths(g, from = starts[[i_s]], to = finals[[i_f]])[[1]]
      },
      error = function(cond) {
        message("failed at starts-nr=", i_s, ", finals-nr=", i_f); return(as.integer(NA))
      }
    )
    res_collect[[tmp]] <- res
    tmp <- tmp + 1
  }
}
```

The problem:

```
res_collect[!is.na(res_collect)]
# [[1]]
# + 3/8 vertices, named, from 60df173:
#   [1] A1  A2  A3a
# 
# [[2]]
# + 3/8 vertices, named, from 60df173:
#   [1] A1  A2  A3b
# 
# [[3]]
# + 3/8 vertices, named, from 60df173:
#   [1] B1  B2a B3
```

1 path is missing: B1 -> B2b -> B3.

Comment: Please explain the problem in plain English. Don't use code to communicate a concept. "Duplicate path" is not clear—you should define it.

Comment: "Duplicate" means that different intermediate products (=vertices) are not shown in the result. I edited my post.

Comment: You still did not describe the task you want to accomplish. Can you explain what you want to do in plain English?

Comment: For example, "I want to find all simple paths (with no repeating vertices, of any length) from any source vertex to any sink vertex of a directed graph." Once again, please explain the problem in full in human language, not in code. The code does not communicate what you are trying to do.

Comment: I believe I explained it in human language. I don't believe I explained it in animal language.

Comment: @r.user.05apr My previous answer was not correct. Please see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
do.call(
  c,
  lapply(
    starts,
    all_simple_paths,
    graph = g,
    to = finals
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
+ 3/4 vertices, named, from fb6335c:
[1] A1  A2  A3a

[[2]]
+ 3/4 vertices, named, from fb6335c:
[1] A1  A2  A3b

[[3]]
+ 3/4 vertices, named, from fb6335c:
[1] B1  B2a B3

[[4]]
+ 3/4 vertices, named, from fb6335c:
[1] B1  B2b B3
```

Comment: This is not quite correct. You don't need to decompose the graph. That makes no difference (and doesn't eliminate pairs of sources/sinks between which there is no path, consider `graph_from_literal(1-+2-+3-+4,5-+3,2-+6)`). However, you need to loop over the `starts` in some way. The `from` argument of `all_simple_paths` takes a single vertex, not a collection of vertices. Only the first one will be considered.

Comment: So something like `unlist( lapply(starts, function (f) all_simple_paths(g, f, finals)) , recursive = F)`

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, thank you for correcting me. you are right. I updated my answer. I used `decompose` since I was thinking of the divide-and-conquer policy to handle large networks with many clusters, but it seems the overhead of `decompse` is heavy.